# easyocr not working with cpu only on Windows

Tags: python, pytorch, ocr, easyocr

I was succesful using easyocr on my computer with gpu and cuda, but now I have to use it also on machine with only cpu.
After following the installation guide from https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/install/ and installing pytorch from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ choosing stable/widnows/pip/python/cpu I just copied example from tutorial https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/tutorial/ saving the example picture from the website.

I've used pip to install both pytorch, by running pip3 `install torch torchvision torchaudio` and `pip install easyocr` in my venv.
I've also tried adding opencv-python, sice I've read that sometimes it can help.
Imports semm to work fine, I've also used

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

to check if pytorch is installed properly.
The problem is, after running the most basic script from tutorial:

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_tra', 'en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('./data/chinese_tra.jpg')
print(result)
```

There is no output, only this message:

```
Using CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.
```

I've also tried using different images that worked on my machine with GPU, so I think this isn't a problem with image.

Any suggestions on what should I check/do differently to make easyocr work on machine with only cpu?

**Edit:**
I've tried the same approach and steps on machine with cpu only, but linux (ubuntu 20.04). It works fine then.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not sure if this is wat you are asking, but I've used test image from tutorial (chinese_tra.jpg)

Comment: And also, as I mentioned - I used images hat worked on my machine with gpu, so I don't think that the problem is with images.

Comment: Oh, if that's a tutorial then it should be fine.  I haven't used EasyOCR, I was just here for the [cpu] tag, but this question isn't about CPUs and how they work, it's about easyocr, so I edited tags.  I only skimmed a tiny bit of the question, missed those important parts.

Comment: You're reporting a bug, either on documentation or code, but in the wrong place. Check the supplier's bugtracker for existing reports and optionally file your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False, verbose=False)
```